# How to add local HTML anchors for sections with Doxia?

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin, doxia

In a Maven site doc I use code like this for sections:

```
<section name="Hibernate statistics">
  Foo
</section>
```

How do I tell Doxia I want the section name/title to be an HTML local anchor? http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/doxia-apt.html#Anchors does talk about this but I've been unable to apply it to `<section>`s.

Comment: I have the same question for the apt style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to do it "properly". However, there's a pretty simple and painless workaround; use the `id` attribute:

```
<section name="Hibernate statistics" id="hibernate-statistics">
  Foo
</section>
```

`id` ends up in the HTML markup as-is. Most browsers nowadays support using `id`s as anchors: `http://server/page.html#hibernate-statistics`